# Есть 2 кнопки с типом submit, как сделать, чтобы одна из них не реагировала на Enter?

Tags: html, button

Есть в форме 2 кнопки с типом submit, как сделать, чтобы одна из них не реагировала на Etner?
А то нажимается не та, что нужно

---

**UPD:**

Решил так

```
type="button" onclick="this.form.submit();">
```

Answer (score 2):

Кнопка `submit` предназначена для отправки данных формы на сервер. Если нужно провести некоторую валидацию/модифицирование данных формы перед отправкой, то для этого у формы есть событие `onsubmit`. Таким образом фраза

> нажимается другая кнопка submit

изначально лишена смысла, т.к. наличие нескольких кнопок submit может быть продиктовано исключительно дизайном. Эти кнопки не могут нести разный функционал

Если же Вам нужно навесить на две кнопки различный функционал, то логично будет вместо

```
<input type="submit"
```

использовать

```
<input type="button"
```

Comment: Обе кнопки отправляют данные на сервер, но одна кнопка имеет дополнительную функцию очистки инпута перед отправкой. Моё решение мне подошло.

Answer (score 1):

Есть еще вариант через JS всё зарешать.. e.PreventDefault; Сразу в начале функции, и после делать то, что посчитаешь нужным)

Comment: постарайтесь давать более конкретные и полноценные ответы

Comment: Спасибо. Интересная и полезная функция... но мой вариант проще :)